# IFileOperation and the progress dialog

Tags: c++, windows-7, modal-dialog, progressdialog, windows-explorer

so, I am working on this shell namespace extension that handles a kind of ZIP file (let's call it ZOP) like a folder.
Everything is in place, and file operations are processed through `IFileOperation` and `IStream`.

The thing is, when copying a file into my virtual ZOP folder, calling `IStream::Commit` is not trivial, and can take significant time, so I'd like to provide additional feedback to the user (and allow her to cancel the operation).

I already have a progress callback mechanism that kicks in when the stream is committed. What I've done for now is a custom dialog, including a progress bar, that pops up whenever `IStream::Commit` is called.

However, I can't seem to find the `hWnd` of the standard progress dialog so that mine can be modal (which means that my dialog can be hidden by the progress dialog itself, which defeats the purpose of my dialog).

I could go the `IFileOperation::SetProgressDialog` way, creating a bridge to `IOperationsProgressDialog`, but I'd still have to do some dirty code to find the progress bar from a stream I've not created - all I can think of to pass data around is the TLS, and boy do I hate this solution, akin to using a global variable.

Thoughts about retrieving the window handle or subclassing the standard dialog ?

---

***Note:*** I've observed that sometimes, for relatively short operations, the standard dialog appears after the stream is flushed. Which is uncool too, as my custom dialog appears and goes away even before the operations seems to start.

---

***Update***: I've found the progress window using EnumWindows/FindWindowEx as the window has the `Dialog` class with a `DirectUIHWND` child. The funny thing is, when instantiating my dialog using DialogBoxParam() (in a distinct thread from IStream::Commit()), the call hangs even before my dialog is displayed, as it is getting stuck in `NtUserCallHwndParamLock`.

Comment: "which means that my dialog can be hidden by something else" <-- [Your dialog can always be hidden by something else](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx).

Comment: @Billy: oh, no, I did not mean "I want to be the most top-most" :) I just want my dialog to be modal to Explorer's one - we're in the same process. I'll fix the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for spy++, get the class name of the window who's hwnd your looking for and call FindWinow or FindWindowEx.

Comment: Good idea, I'll definitely give it a try. I'm still afraid I won't be able to address the case where Explorer's progress dialog shows up after the copy is done...

Comment: Ah well... All I know now is that the standard progress dialog is a `Dialog`, and there are tens of instances of them. None of which seem to have Explorer as a parent. The interesting thing is that setting Explorer's windows as owner of my own dialog makes it modal to the progress dialog, which is part of what I wanted.